# Give the output printed by java Stack for the input

Tags: data-structures, stack

I am a bit confused on this homework and the data structure of a stack. Essentially the question is:

```
"Give the output printed by java Stack for the input"
```

Below is the input

```
it was - the best - of times - - - it was - the - -
```

the output would be in the answer key

```
was best times of the was the it (1 left on stack)
```

I don't understand how you would receive this output I attempted writing my own stack structure but if I iterate through it I just get first in, first out.

Any help will do I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't stated explicitly, but looking at the input I assume words are pushed onto the stack, while `-` signs are pop operations. If that is the case then the operations are

- push `it`, stack contains `it`;
- push `was`, stack contains `it` `was`;
- pop prints **was**, stack contains `it`;
- push `the`, stack contains `it` `the`;
- push `best`, stack contains `it` `the` `best`;
- pop prints **best**, stack contains `it` `the`;
- push `of`, stack contains `it` `the` `of`;
- push `times`, stack contains `it` `the` `of` `times`;
- pop prints **times**, stack contains `it` `the` `of`;
- pop prints **of**, stack contains `it` `the`;
- pop prints **the**, stack contains `it`;
- push `it`, stack contains `it` `it`;
- push `was`, stack contains `it` `it` `was`;
- pop prints **was**, stack contains `it` `it`;
- push `the`, stack contains `it` `it` `the`;
- pop prints **the**, stack contains `it` `it`;
- pop prints **it**, stack contains `it`.

The words in bold are the output of the pop operations.